# Powershell - Invoke-VMScript - How to insert a variable into the script variable?

Tags: powershell, invoke

I'm trying to use an invoke-vmscript to modify IPV4 parameters on all our servers using their macaddress.

```
$vms = import-csv C:\temp\adapter_vm.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach($vm in $vms){ 

 $serveur = $vm.name
 $mac = $vm.macaddress
 $dns = "$interfaceindex = get-netadapter | where-object MacAddress -Like $($mac) | select-object InterfaceIndex; set-dnsclient -InterfaceIndex $interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex -UseSuffixWhenRegistering $true -RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $true -ConnectionSpecificSuffix test"

 Invoke-VMScript -VM $serveur -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $dns -GuestUser secret -GuestPassword secret

}
```

My problem is that the $interfaceindex is not recognized by the remote computer.

set-dnsclient needs the interfaceindex, that is the reason I'm using $interfaceindex.

Could you help me ?

Maybe there is another way ?

Thank you !

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

= : The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
 file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
 included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
 At line:1 char:5
 + & { = get-netadapter | where-object MacAddress -Like 00-50-56-a1-33-61 |
 select- ...
 +     ~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (=:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx
    ception
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Set-DnsClient : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
 'InterfaceIndex'. Cannot convert value ".InterfaceIndex" to type
 "System.UInt32[]". Error: "Cannot convert value ".InterfaceIndex" to type
 "System.UInt32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
 At line:1 char:134
 + ... InterfaceIndex .InterfaceIndex -UseSuffixWhenRegistering False
 -RegisterThisConn ...
 +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-DnsClient], ParameterBindi
    ngArgumentTransformationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-DnsClie
    nt

Comment: Try adding a backtick in front of the initial `$` sign.

Comment: I just tried and it still does not work. The error is the following :            Set-DnsClient : Missing an argument for parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.UInt32[]' and try again. At line:1 char:133 + ... set-dnsclient -InterfaceIndex -UseSuffixWhenRegistering True -RegisterThisConn ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-DnsClient], ParameterB indingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Set-DnsClient –

Comment: Did you try putting the text into a file and passing the file as your script text? Or possibly changing $dns line from double quotes to single quotes. As it is trying to convert the variables into variables for the DNS string input.

Comment: @RobertCotterman I already tried to use single quotes but in this case my $mac is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Using a wmiobject is actually better since it works on both Windows 2008 and 2012.

```
$vms = import-csv C:\temp\adapter_vm.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach($vm in $vms){ 

 $serveur = $vm.name
 $mac = $vm.macaddress
 $dns = "(get-wmiobject -class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where-object {`$_.MacAddress -Like ""$($mac)""}).SetDynamicDNSRegistration(`$TRUE, `$TRUE)"

 Invoke-VMScript -VM $serveur -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $dns -hostcredential $domaincred

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two problems with your `$dns`string..

First: Try what @Boxdog said and add a backtick in front of the initial `$`sign.
Second: You have to use paranthesis around the `-InterfaceIndex $($interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex)`.

Your full string should like like that:

```
$dns = "`$interfaceindex = get-netadapter | where-object MacAddress -Like $($mac) | select-object InterfaceIndex; set-dnsclient -InterfaceIndex $($interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex) -UseSuffixWhenRegistering $true -RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $true -ConnectionSpecificSuffix test"
```

Give it a try.

EDIT: Maybe you need to add a backtick before the second `$interfaceIndex`as well.. (`$interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex)

EDIT2:
It is sometimes difficult to understand the use of all those signs :-) . In the documentation for [set-dnsClient](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj590776(v=wps.630).aspx) parameter, it shows that for the parameter InterfaceIndex it "Specifies the **index number** of the interface."
With your code `$interfaceindex = get-netadapter | where-object MacAddress -Like $($mac) | select-object InterfaceIndex` you have **values** in your variable..
 Try it with something like this `($interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex[0])` (don't forget the backtick after the "(" paranthesis)

Comment: Set-DnsClient : Missing an argument for parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. Specify a
parameter of type 'System.UInt32[]' and try again.
At line:1 char:133
+ ...  set-dnsclient -InterfaceIndex  -UseSuffixWhenRegistering True
-RegisterThisConn ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-DnsClient], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Set-DnsClient

Comment: I think it's better but the interfaceindex is still a problem. I have difficulties to understand the user of all the ", ', (,[ in such a context !

Comment: like this  -InterfaceIndex $(`$interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex[0])  ? I tried with and without the backtick and it keeps saying that indexinterface has no value.

Comment: The only $ that shouldn't be escaped (backticked) is the $mac. So the interfaceindex and the true variables should all be backticked. A better way to test this is display $dns and see what comes out. Only thing that should come out is the mac because that's dependent upon the loop. Otherwise it should all be created on the far end.

Comment: I added a backtick on all $ except $mac and it stil does not work. When I had the backtick to $($interfaceindex.interfaceindex) after the first parenthesis, the error is that the term $interfaceindex.interfaceindex is not recognized as an applet command.

Comment: Did you try the `$interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex[0]`? To troublshoot that further you could try to run your command step-by-step on the remote server.. First run `$interfaceindex = get-netadapter | where-object MacAddress -Like $($mac) | select-object InterfaceIndex` . I would even hardcode the Mac-Address. Then check whats inside `$interfaceindex.InterfaceIndex`. Then try to `set-dnsclient` and use the desired **interfaceindex** (0?). If all that works, give it a try with the invoke command.

Comment: I found out that using wmiobject works better in my situation. But I tried to modified the get-netadapter command, and I found out that the problem was the `where-object MacAddress -like` that I changed to      where-object {`$_.MacAddress -Like ""$($mac)""}`.   Thank you very much for your help !! Your backtick "tips" really helped me out !